# About service discovery and proxy

Tags: soa, service-discovery

I am reading several [articles](http://microservices.io/patterns/) about micro-service.

At the [server-side service discovery](http://microservices.io/patterns/server-side-discovery.html) part, I am drawn to the Kubernetes and Marathon's style of running a proxy on each host/docker-container that functions as a server-side discovery router.

By doing this, we can move all code coupled with service registration/discovery and circuit-breaker to that proxy.

By configuring the router of each host/docker-container, the proxy can be transparent to the service and the network, and we can implement some gossip strategy to make the proxies sync their knowledge of the network. Seems like an excellent solution.

Can anyone explain to me what are the drawbacks of doing this and recommend some open-sourced solution implemented such kind of thing?

Comment: Did you found any solution? I need to apply server-side service discovery pattern for my project. Although i read many articles about it, i am not sure which technology is solution for me because i am newbie for micro-service architecture. I found many reliable solution for client side discovery and i have clear understanding for it but i did not find any easy solution for server-side one. İf you found solution for your case, please inform me from here:) i am looking for your advices.